# Unintuitive results when Expanding Binary Classification to Multiclass

Tags: r, random-forest, multiclass-classification, binary

I have aproblem where I need to predict when a Truck arrives to pickup something.

Say we have formulated that a binary classification model, where

> 0: The truck coming for pickup today
>
> 1:The truck comes for pickup sometime in the future after today.

Next, it was decided to expand the 2 class problem to a three class one, as follows:

> 0: The truck coming for pickup today,
>
> 1: The truck comes for pickup tomorrow
>
> 3: The Truck comes for pickup sometime in the future after tomorrow.

So, the 0-class remains as it is. 
A Random Forest (ranger in R) model was applied in both situations and the results compared. SInce the 0-class remains as is, we would expect the number of 0-predictions to be close from both models. But that is not the case: there is about a 30% difference in the number of 0-class predictions in the two models, which I find unintuitive. Is this behavior not really as unintuitive or is somethign wrong?

Comment: How about the accuracy or whatever metric you have chosen for the first class?

Answer (score 0):

Trucks could come any of the days in the future, and one could represent this as a histogram. Since there is an infinite days in the future, the histogram with N bins cuts off the distribution and the last bin represents after-N days. With a 2-bin histogram, a lot of samples will be in that second bin. Some of these are quite close to the decision border between classes, some are really far away. Some were in class 0 but just barely, because of the large distance to samples far away in class 1. When introducing another class/bin, the samples that were close the boundary from both sides will likely move into the new bin. Note that the decision boundaries for all classes will shift!

Your classes represent a discretization of a continuous variable (time that the truck arrive). You might want to increase the number of classes to more closely represent the underlying distribution. For instance by going to 2/4/6 hour periods, or increasing the number of days. Or having a continuous output.